# Tools required to build a WinUI3 MSIX packed and signed application from the command line

Tags: .net, winui-3

I have ported my C# store application from UWP over to WinUI.

I am finding it hard to find what tool(s) I need to build, package, and sign on our build machine, i.e. building from the command line. I can't find any "build tools" for Windows App SDK / WinUI3, it seems to just point to a full Visual studio? (surely we don't need to install a full VS onto a build machine?) - i.e. [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/set-up-your-development-environment?tabs=vs-2022-17-1-a%2Cvs-2022-17-1-b) only has Visual studios, but no CLI build tools references?

It is then not clear if I need something different to create the `MSIX` (I am trying both a standalone and the single project MSIX).

And then finally to sign, do we then need to use the `Signtool.exe`, where I assume I can use my own signing certificate, rather than one allocated from the store (which was always very confusing to update)

I have been through so many documents, and end up at the starting one, so any insights here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/package-and-deploy/ci-for-winui3?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) and [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/github-actions-for-desktop-apps) for an example of how to create CI/CD workflows for Windows desktop apps using GitHub Actions.

The Windows Application Packaging project is built using `msbuild`:

```
# Build the Windows Application Packaging project
- name: Build the Windows Application Packaging Project (wapproj)
  run: msbuild $env:Solution_Path /p:Platform=$env:TargetPlatform /p:Configuration=$env:Configuration /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=$env:BuildMode /p:AppxBundle=$env:AppxBundle /p:PackageCertificateKeyFile=$env:SigningCertificate /p:PackageCertificatePassword=${{ secrets.Pfx_Key }}
  env:
    AppxBundle: Never
    BuildMode: SideloadOnly
    Configuration: Debug
    TargetPlatform: ${{ matrix.targetplatform }}
```

If you intend to upload your package to the store, you don't need to sign it with your own certificate.